# How install ZendQueue to ZF2 2.1.5

Tags: zend-framework2, rabbitmq, amqp, composer-php, zend-queue

I need to implement sending messages to the queue rabbitmq(amqp) from ZF2.

I did not find the module in ZF2 to work with a queue.

It was decided to expand adapter of ZendQueue. (Maybe somebody knows another way)

I tried to install ZendQueue at help composer, but composer is fail, because his have

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "2.0.*"
},
```

My version ZF2 is 2.1.5

Used composer command for installed:

```
php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-queue:dev-develop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For today it is already fixed in repo

Answer (score 0):

In your composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "2.0.*",
    "zendframework/zend-queue": "dev-master"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```